# Monogame Content Pipeline not building spritefont - index out of range?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and the Monogame framework 3.5. My PC is running Windows 10 64 bit.

My SpriteFonts are not building and give this error:

[image]

My regularFont.spritefont code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!--
 This file contains an xml description of a font, and will be read by the XNA
 Framework Content Pipeline. Follow the comments to customize the appearance
 of the font in your game, and to change the characters which are available 
 to draw with.
  -->
  <XnaContent 
xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics">
    <Asset Type="Graphics:FontDescription">

  <!--
  Modify this string to change the font that will be imported.
  -->




<FontName>Arial</FontName>


  <!--
  Size is a float value, measured in points. Modify this value to change
  the size of the font.
  -->

           <Size>12</Size>

  <!--
  Spacing is a float value, measured in pixels. Modify this value to change
  the amount of spacing in between characters.
  -->
  <Spacing>0</Spacing>

  <!--
  UseKerning controls the layout of the font. If this value is true, kerning information
  will be used when placing characters.
  -->
  <UseKerning>true</UseKerning>

  <!--
  Style controls the style of the font. Valid entries are "Regular", "Bold", "Italic",
  and "Bold, Italic", and are case sensitive.
  -->
  <Style>Regular</Style>

  <!--
  If you uncomment this line, the default character will be substituted if you draw
  or measure text that contains characters which were not included in the font.
  -->
  <!-- <DefaultCharacter>*</DefaultCharacter> -->

  <!--
  CharacterRegions control what letters are available in the font. Every
  character from Start to End will be built and made available for drawing. The
  default range is from 32, (ASCII space), to 126, ('~'), covering the basic Latin
  character set. The characters are ordered according to the Unicode standard.
  See the documentation for more information.
  -->
  <CharacterRegions>
    <CharacterRegion>
      <Start>&#32;</Start>
      <End>&#126;</End>
    </CharacterRegion>
  </CharacterRegions>
</Asset>
```

I have already tried reinstalling the C++ packages, putting the .TFF file inside the fonts folder, renaming the  to Arial.tff or Arial-Regular. I have tried numerous different fonts.

This is the error when I build the entire project:

```
Building Font C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.ttf
1>      System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'freetype6.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
1>     at SharpFont.FT.FT_Init_FreeType(IntPtr& alibrary)
1>     at SharpFont.Library..ctor()
1>     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics.SharpFontImporter.Import(FontDescription options, String fontName)
1>     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.FontDescriptionProcessor.ImportFont(FontDescription options, Single& lineSpacing, Int32& yOffsetMin,     ContentProcessorContext context, String fontName)
1>     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.FontDescriptionProcessor.Process(FontDescription input, ContentProcessorContext context)
1>C:/Users/David/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Cobra/Cobra/Content/fonts/hiFont.spritefont : error : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    1>  Parameter name: index
```

Can anyone help? This is very peculiar because I've used monogame on a different PC running Win7/Visual Studio 2015 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this through an old github post saying to download a c++ update for visual studio 2012...which I thought had no chance in working but it did

Try downloading and installing this if you have this issue:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-NZ/download/details.aspx?id=30679